Convert time into seconds [removing milliseconds]
I have a Pandas dataframe where, column name 'A' has date and time value (as of now it is of type string).



Column A
Column B




2024-07-11 13:09:37.466
PC2


2024-07-11 13:24:43.03
PC1


May 6 2024 22:49:50
PC5



I am trying to remove milliseconds from time and also only one format which is %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S. So the output should be like below:



Column A
Column B




2024-07-11 13:09:37
PC2


2024-07-11 13:24:43
PC1


2024-05-06 22:49:50
PC5



Convert column A into type datetime, so I can sort later by datetime
I tried below below solutions but both are giving error. I think due to number of different digits in milliseconds
df['Column A'] = pd.to_datetime(Df['event time']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['Column A'] = Df['Column A'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))


"but both are giving error. "  -- what error, precisely?

Code
df['Column A'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df['Column A'].str.split('.').str[0], format='mixed')

df
    Column A            Column B
0   2024-07-11 13:09:37 PC2
1   2024-07-11 13:24:43 PC1
2   2024-05-06 22:49:50 PC5


Example Code
import pandas as pd
data = {'Column A': ['2024-07-11 13:09:37.466', '2024-07-11 13:24:43.03', 'May 6 2024 22:49:50'], 'Column B': ['PC2', 'PC1', 'PC5']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

